# Multiple Select SQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

app.php

```
 <thead>
        <tr>
    <th>#</th
    <th>Item</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
$i = 1;
while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['app_cn'] != '') {
        echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['item_name'] . '</td>
        <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['counter'] . '" style="cursor:pointer;" class="checkbox"></td>
   </tr>';
    }
}
echo "</tbody></table>";

  <a class="button" href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();" onclick="f1.action='addpr.php'; return true;"><span><b>Add to Purchase Request</b></span></a>
```

addpr.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
    $id=$_POST['checkbox'];
    $N = count($id);
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
        $result1 = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT item_name, item_description, counter
    FROM app
    WHERE counter='$id[$i]'
        ");
```

Why there's no output after I submit, but when I remove the `WHERE counter='$id[$i]'` in addpr.php it displays all the records in the database. I want to show only records that check in checkbox.

Comment: echo $id[$i]; what you get?

Comment: @HarishSingh nothing display

Answer (score 0):

try this, no loop required

```
if(!isset($_POST['checkbox']) && count($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $val = implode("','",$_POST['checkbox']);

    $result1 = $mysqli->query("
        SELECT item_name, item_description, counter
        FROM app
        WHERE counter IN ('$val')
    ");
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: check your selected checkbox with if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {  }

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object again :(

Comment: print_r($_POST['checkbox']); use this what you are getting, please show here

Comment: in my original code it displays Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )

Comment: in your codes it displays Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: you are getting same after checked the checkbox also